# Do you need to include the copyright for imported libraries?

Tags: licensing, python

My new code imports libraries from other sources (pandas,tqdm,plotly to name the big ones). Do I need to reference them in my LICENSE.md?

Or is it enough to simply mention them in the README.md?

Comment: What licenses are they?

Comment: Do you distribute the libraries as well? Then in that case you need to abide by any license requirements of those.

Comment: @Shimmy the licenses for small libraries are all MIT or related

Comment: @Brandin I have a requirements.txt file for people to run the pip command to install libs, that way its the user that is distributing the library right?

Comment: @Thomas, the library is GNUv2 ([PostGIS](http://postgis.net/)).